# Uncaught Error: This method has been removed in JSZip 3.0, jszip.min.js:13 (REACT)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jszip

I have a json file and i want to export this as an excel file. I also want to add some styles but I am encountering this error. I'm not even using the jszip library. How can i solve this problem ? Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReactExport from 'react-data-export';
import MainData from '../data/data.json';

const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;

function HomeScreen() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(MainData);
  }, []);

  console.log(data.content);

  const DataSet = [
    {
      columns: [
        {
          title: 'ID',
          style: { font: { sz: '18', bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 125 },
        },
        {
          title: 'Last Update',
          style: { font: { sz: '18', bold: true } },
          width: { wch: 30 },
        },
        ...
        
      ],
      data: data?.content?.map((item) => {
        return [
          [
            { value: item?.action, style: { font: { sz: '14' } } },
            { value: item?.elementID, style: { font: { sz: '14' } } },
            {
              value: item?.id,
              style: {
                font: { color: { rgb: 'ffffff' } },
                fill: { patternType: 'solid', fgColor: { rgb: '3461eb' } },
              },
            },
            {
              value: item?.name,
              style: {
                font: { color: { rgb: 'ffffff' } },
                fill: { patternType: 'solid', fgColor: { rgb: 'eb1207' } },
              },
            },
            ...
          ],
        ];
      }),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Data</h1>
      <ExcelFile filename="data" element={<button>Export</button>}>
        <ExcelSheet dataSet={DataSet} name="Datareport" />
      </ExcelFile>
      <ul>
        <li>id: {data.id}</li>
        <li>last update: {data.lastUpdated}</li>
        <li>members: {data.members}</li>
        ...
      </ul>

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>action</th>
            <th>elementID</th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            ...
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data?.content?.map((item, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{item?.action}</td>
              <td>{item?.elementID}</td>
              <td>{item?.id}</td>
              ...
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

I had a lot of bugs about fs module and after that i have this. I searched on google there is some answers but I am getting an error like this without using the library.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6wTi.png)